# R: ddply for an updating function

Tags: r

I have a silly function, which updates the value of S in the length of the vector called ACC by delta1 and delta2.

```
Sstart=0           #a starting value for S
ACC=c(1,1,0,1,1)   #accuracy: 0 or 1
f=c(1,1,1,1,0)     #feedback: 0 or 1
ID=rep(1,5)        #ID of the participant
delta1=seq(1,5,1)
delta2=seq(1,5,1)
m<-as.matrix(expand.grid(delta1=delta1, delta2=delta2)) #all the possible combination of       delta1 and delta2
```

The function is the following. When the feedback (f) is 1, it updates S by delta1, when the ffedback is 0, then with delta2. Delta1 and delta2 ranges from 1 to 5 and I increment them separately.

```
silly_function<-function(delta1, delta2,ACC,f,Sstart){
  S = Sstart
  for (i in 1:length(ACC)){
    if (ACC[i]==1 & f[i]==1){
      S[i+1]=S[i]+delta1
    }
    else if (ACC[i]==1 & f[i]==0){
      S[i+1]=S[i]+delta2
    }
    else if (ACC[i]==0){                        
      S[i+1]=S[i]
    }
  }
  return(S)
}
```

I call the function

```
N=length(delta1)*length(delta2) 
SMat<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=N, ncol=(length(ACC)+1)) #matrix for the data

for (i in 1:N){
  SMat[i,] <- silly_function(m[i,1],m[i,2],ACC,f,Sstart)}
```

**My problem:**
The function works perfectly for 1 subject, but I cannot find a clever way for applying it for all my subjects separately (I have a data frame where all the data from my participants are in one data frame) and combine the results into one matrix or data frame. I wanted to use ddply from the plyr package, but I couldn’t find an example similar to mine to modify it and get some idea how to implement it in this case. 
Thank you very much for your comments/hints in advance!

*My input for two participants*

```
ID    Feedback    ACC
1       1          1
1       1          1
1       1          0
1       1          1
1       0          1
2       1          1
2       1          1
2       0          1
2       1          0
2       1          1
```

*Actual output*

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 
0  1  2  2  3  4 #row1
0  2  4  4  6  7
.
.
0  5  10  10  15 20 #row25
```

For subject 1 the output is: 
25 * 6 (rows*columns) matrix: 25 rows because I update S by all possible combinations of delta1 and delta2. the first column is always 0 because Sstart is 0.

*Desired output*
Basically the same as for subject 1 but with all the subjects data

1-25 rows for subject 1

26-50 rows for subject 2...

Comment: I am still confused on about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: sorry, maybe I was not clear. In the example I call the function for one participant N times, since N is the all possible combination of delta1 and delta2. My aim is to call it not only for one subject but for all of them, so I don't need to repeat it for each subject.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your input and desired output?

Comment: I updated it, i hope it is more clear, let me know if my problem is still not clearly written.